# Using a Flitch re-inforce a notch in LVL

Tags: basement

I am looking to make a small notch in an LVL beam in my basement. In full transparency, I have installed a golf simulator in my basement, and I need another 2-3 inches of height to swing a driver freely. I would like to make a notch that is roughly 2 ft wide by 3" deep. My basement has 2x12" LVL Boise Cascade joists and every other beam has a sistered joist for added support that I had the builder include for strength. The notch would be in the highlighted area, which is roughly 3ft from a steel structural support beam going through the middle of the basement.

What I am thinking would be to add a steel plate on each side of the notched joists making a "flitch plate". The steel plates would be 5ft long x 5" high x 1/2" in depth. Use bolts to run through the plates and the sistered LVL's to connect each steel plate to the LVL's to "sandwich" the LVL's that are notched between the steel plates.

Would this work? Would I need a different size steel beams? What type of fasteners are needed (would need to use bolts).

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: I think it's interesting that you have this down to knowing you need an extra 3" of height.  I'm not a golfer _at all_, but does this not change with the club you are using?  You're sure that 3" out of that one joist is going to do the job?  Not arguing, just curious.

Comment: I'm a 2 handicap in golf and my swing is grooved really well to know that 3" of height will work to swing a driver freely. I have a padded protected area that I will sometimes just barely hit, so 3" should be more than enough. Every other club but the driver is much shorter, so I don't come even close to making contact.

Comment: I'd just hate for you to commit to all that work and then find you were wrong by 2".  Have you ever lifted a 60"x6"x0.5" hunk of steel?  Why so thick?

Comment: Yeah, I've done something similar, only with a _beam_ instead of a joist, and 2x 1/4" mild steel was adequate.

Comment: Protip: Save the cut-out piece so you can stick it back in when you go to sell the house. That notch would make a lot of folks nervous.

Comment: @isherwood - that's the beauty of this house, I'll die in it... LOL.

Comment: @Harper - yes, I only just barely hit the ceiling as it is now. From my hitting mat to the padding it's 9ft 2". So if I have 3" inches, I have no worries hitting anything. And the piece of steel I'll be using is 60" x 5" x .05", it says roughly 60 lbs for hot rolled steel online for that much.

Comment: I would use thinner pieces of steel and back them with 2-by's. To have any strength, the steel must remain in a vertical plane and not "bow out". One way to prevent that is thick steel.  The other way is sandwich it in wood, with the steel providing the tensile strength and the wood compressive strength. It's a composite, but you are already proposing a composite, so it's not a big leap.

Comment: @Harper - so 2x4's on the outside of the steel strips? That's not overkill? I was thinking .5" steel so it's still very strong without having to worry about sagging, etc.

Comment: Could you rotate the simulator so your swing goes parallel with the joists instead of perpendicular?